# Making option to choose correct resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, resolution

I am making a video game and have problem with screen resolutions.
Earlier, a few month ago, I asked very similar question.

[Need images with lower resolution "stretched" to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199156/need-images-with-lower-resolution-stretched-to-screen-size)

Back then, it seemed the answer I got (using ViewBox) was perfect, but now I am getting problems.

I want every and every image and control in my game to have a few different possible variations fit for resolutions. 
For example, if user sets resolution 800x600, all images and buttons are reduced to correct sizes. But I do want my game to be fullscreen only, not windowed.

So, if the resolution is lower then end-user monitor has, all images must be stretched and look "fuzzy". And if higher, part of it must be outside of screen.

For now, my code just sets resolution to end-user monitor, whatever it is. That's absolutely not what I want.

What I get:

[image]

A very crude example of what I need:

[image]

I'll show xaml as its now. Of course it isn't full, but I'll show the beginning and a few elements, so you'll know how it's built.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="wdwMain" x:Class="RealityIncognita.MainWindow"
    Height="900" Width="1600" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" Cursor="Cross" WindowStyle="None" Loaded="wdwMain_Loaded">

<Viewbox x:Name="viewMain" Stretch="Fill">
    <Grid x:Name="areaContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="900" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1600">

      <Grid x:Name="areaMain">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Images/Interface/main_interface.jpg"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Label x:Name="lblTextOutput" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="52" Margin="55,726,31,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1514" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnExit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="1464,771,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" Click="btnExit_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Interface/Blank.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="12,0,6,0"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
               </Button.Template>
            </Button>

            <Grid x:Name="areaShowers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="700" Margin="1653,790,-1561,-590" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1508"  IsVisibleChanged="areaShowers_IsVisibleChanged">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Images/Rooms/Showers/shower_room.jpg" />
                </Grid.Background>


                <Button x:Name="objShowersSoap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="613,423,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveAnyObject" RenderTransformOrigin="11.706,1.897" Click="objShowersSoap_Click" MouseEnter="objShowersSoap_MouseEnter">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Rooms/Showers/soap.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Image x:Name="imgShowersOpenMachine" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Resources/Images/Rooms/Showers/drying_machine_open.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.808,0.471" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Button>                   
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="areaLockerRoom" Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1508" IsVisibleChanged="areaLockerRoom_IsVisibleChanged" Margin="1653,17,-1561,0" MouseDown="areaLockerRoom_MouseDown" MouseEnter="areaLockerRoom_MouseEnter" MouseMove="areaLockerRoom_MouseMove">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Images/Rooms/LockerRoom/locker_room_ready.png"/>
                </Grid.Background>

                <Button x:Name="objLockerRoomCrowbar" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="243" Margin="604,328,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" MouseEnter="objCrowbar_MouseEnter" Panel.ZIndex="1" Click="objCrowbar_Click" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveAnyObject">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Rooms/LockerRoom/crowbar_only.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>

                <Button x:Name="objLockerRoomOdyssey" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="797,638,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" Click="objBookOdyssey_Click" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveAnyObject" MouseEnter="objBookOdyssey_MouseEnter">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Rooms/LockerRoom/img_book_odyssey.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="objLockerRoomEdda" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="1335,549,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveAnyObject" Click="objBookEdda_Click" MouseEnter="objBookEdda_MouseEnter">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Rooms/LockerRoom/img_book_edda.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
```

To summarize the structure is like that:

Main Window - Viewbox - areaContainer (main grid) - game areas (grids) - images and buttons for each grid

**To summarize:**
What I get: game screens are set for end-user monitor resolution.
What I need: game sets all images to specific resolution, makes it "fuzzy" if resolution is LOWER then end-user's, and "cuts" it if it is HIGHER.

Thank you in advance,
Evgenie

**ADDED:**
If I understand correctly how it works - the container grid that includes all other items should be resized, images should become smaller (by default they are 1600x900), if needed. Then, this container grid must fit user's screen resolution, staying with small images quality.

And to simplify it even more: **Can I make large images smaller, then change them to be big again (and lose quality) directly in Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 0):

Actually simply adjusting the viewbox did the trick.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="viewMain" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

And in code, I had to change MaxWidth and MaxHeight, instead of regular ones.

```
viewMain.MaxWidth = 1024;
viewMain.MaxHeight = 768;
```